# Desktop app converted to raspberry pi 3

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi3, desktop-bridge

We have a PC desktop application, can we convert to an appx using desktop bridge and run on a raspberry pi 3 ARM device

Comment: have you tried it? how can we know what dependencies you have (and i they work on the rpi 3)? please add more Details to your question! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desktop applications are only supported on the desktop SKU. Packaging them as an .appx package alone does not make them work on other SKUs. You would need to migrate to a full UWP solution to make it work on devices other than desktop/laptop/tablet.